# Default datetime format value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

What's the default value for datetime in sql? I have a 6/8/2012 14:07 value but sql doesn't accept it. Please help!

Comment: Try adding the :00 seconds at the end, it's generally `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:SS` or `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS`

Comment: which RDBMS? SQL Server? MySQL? Do you also mean the default format?

Comment: Is that the 6th August, or the 8th June? If you use a different date format, or explicitly convert, you may find your troubles go away.

Comment: it's YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about your date format and your RDBMS. (I guess its mysql from your previous questions' tags )

Most of the RDMSs will accept `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss`

you you could try ..

If your date is 8th Jun

```
 2012-06-08 14:07:00
```

If your date is 6th Aug
or

```
 2012-08-06 14:07:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the sql date format dd/mm/yyyy hh:min:sec (pm/am) 9/28/2012 4:19:50 PM